# MySQL : Get lastest updated row from 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, datetime, compare, max, union

Assume that I have 2 tables below:

articles_1

```
+----------------------------------------+
|id    |  title      |  updated_date     |
+--------------------+-------------------+
|1     |article 1    | 2013/10/4 12:24:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|2     |article 2    | 2013/10/2 12:25:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|3     |article 3    | 2013/10/3 12:26:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

articles_2

```
+----------------------------------------+
|id    |  title      |  updated_date     |
+----------------------------------------+
|1     |article 4    | 2013/10/1 10:24:00|
+----------------------------------------+
|2     |article 5    | 2013/10/5 10:25:00|
+----------------------------------------+
|3     |article 6    | 2013/10/3 10:26:00|
+----------------------------------------+
```

How can I retreive the **lastest updated article** from these 2 tables?
In a short way, how can I get the "**article 5**" in the articles_2 table base on its updated_date (2013/10/5 10:25:00 is the **max** updated date)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have two tables with the same kind of data in it, but you can use a `UNION` to put them together, then select the top row from the union:

```
SELECT id, title, updated_date
FROM (
    SELECT id, title, updated_date
    FROM articles_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, title, updated_date
    FROM articles_2
) a
ORDER BY updated_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8fb0/1)

Comment: Actually I have 3 tables that have the same structure, but never mind. Your solution works perfect. Thanks. I'll mark your answer as accepted ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

Using SUBSELECT and UNION statements:

```
SELECT id, title, updated_date, origin
FROM (
    SELECT id, title, updated_date, 'articles_1' AS origin
    FROM articles_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, title, updated_date, 'articles_2' AS origin
    FROM articles_2
) a
ORDER BY updated_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

With the column 'origin', you can know in **where table was the registry**.

Comment: Great advise with 'origin' column. Thanks!